# MKMapview loading slowly in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mkmapview

Sometimes get this blank screen in mapView

[image]

And getting slowly in loading mapView.
but I can find location latitude and longitude value. Any idea for this. I need help.

Comment: it's look like this http://imgur.com.80bola.com/rBVWTeD